# pause countdown javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, timer, seconds

http://jsfiddle.net/vvccvvcc/mu45bptk/

how do I pause the timer? I want it to stop when it gets to 5 seconds

I tried this as seen in the fiddle

```
else {
        isWaiting = true;
        seconds--;

        if (seconds == 5) {
            seconds=seconds;}     




    }
```

does not work

Comment: why not just clear the interval again? `clearInterval( countdownTimer );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer is initialized by `setInterval(GameTimer, 1000);`

```
    if (seconds == 5) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    } else {
         seconds--;
    }
```

You will need to clear the interval in order to stop calling the function. Alternatively if you don't want to clear the interval you can say

```
    if (seconds > 5) {
         seconds--;
    }
```

The way you've written it, `second` is decreased regardless of the condition (since it's before the `if` statement) and therefore, `second = second` becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mu45bptk/2/

```
var isWaiting = false;
var isRunning = false;
var seconds = 10;
var countdownTimer;
var finalCountdown = false;

function GameTimer() {
    if (isWaiting) {
        return;   
    }
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
    }
    document.getElementById('waiting_time').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {

        if (finalCountdown) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        } else {
            finalCountdown = true;
        }

    } else {             
        if (seconds == 5) {            
            isWaiting = true;  
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }




    }
}
countdownTimer = setInterval(GameTimer, 1000);
```

You need to set isWaiting only if `seconds == 5` and then check isWaiting on every run of `GameTimer()`